# How can I remove few enties in the $UpdatedBy field in a particular documents

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

With out modifying the option in the database properties Advanced tab Option "Limit entries in $UpdatedBy Fields " --- How can I remove few of the $UpdatedBy field entries in documents.

I have a requirement to remove few of the $UpdatedBy field entities in one particular document.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ fields are usually maintained by Lotus itself. It is probably not impossible, but this post describe why it is not [feasible](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/DateAllFlatweb/55056dc606ae635d85257865002f88cd?OpenDocument)

If it is absolutely required to do this without changing the database properties, you can consider creating a new document and copy all the items of the previous document (excluding the $ items). This new document will have a new UNID so if any documents are pointing to this document you should fix that also.

Comment: In my form I have not added $UpdatdField. Is it possible to set the Summary Flag to False for this field ? I tried it Domino revert backs the changes ? Any specific reasons for this why domino has revert back my changes ?

Comment: The field is generated by Lotus itself. Any changes you make will be removed by lotus. Either limit the entries by updating the database properties, or replace the document as described above.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to edit the $UpdatedBy field.

(see more discussion [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/0/79b3f21848ff8386852572040037b513?OpenDocument))

Answer (score 1):

You could use DXL to export the document without the $UpdatedBy field and then import it back in as a new document.  I've used this technique successfully on entire databases where I needed to clear the history from all the documents and from all the database design elements.

The standard NotesDXLExporter NotesDXLImporter help code worked for me, and then I just added a property setting:

```
exporter.OmitItemNames = "updatedby"
```

When the documents are reimported, the $UpdatedBy field is recreated, of course, but your name is the only entry.